# Disable googlebot fetching www

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I have www redirect in .htaccess.
So `www.example.com` gets 301 redirect to `example.com`
But google still tries to fetch `www.example.com` also.

Can i disable googlebot fetcing `www.example.com`?
Eg from webaster tools or robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Webmaster Tools you can set your preferred hostname – with or without www, but this comes with no guarantee from Google. As you have 301s from www to non-www, Googlebot will probably respect your wish.